# MySQL LINES TERMINATED BY

Tags: mysql

What are the potential choices for `LINES TERMINATED BY` in MySQL?

I have a CSV file that I am trying to upload and neither \r\n, \n, or \r work.

Comment: Maybe you should write a filter, that reads your input CSV line by line then writes something consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Try inspecting the file using a binary-displaying utility like od (http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/1/od). That will show you imediately how your lines are terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with brian.

Query which i used to work are as follows.

```
load data local infile  'test.csv' 
into table test_field fields 
terminated by ','   
lines terminated by '\n'
```